# Enable/Disable an HTML Element With Dynamically Generated Names/Tags

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, html, django

I have a table in HTML where the ID is dynamically generated from a row counter:

```
$(table).find('tbody').append("<tr>name=\"tableRow\"</tr>"
    + "<td>"
      + "<select id=\"shapeSelect_" + rowCount + "></td>"
        + "<option onclick=\"sphereSelect()\" value=\"sphere\">Sphere</option>"
        + "<option onclick=\"cylinderSelect()\" value=\"cylinder\">Cylinder</option>"
      + "</select>"
    + "</td>"
    + "<td><input type=\"text\" id=\"altitude" + rowCount + "\"</td>"
    + "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"maxAlt\" id=\"maxAltitude_" + rowCount + "></td>"
    + "</tr>"
```

I need maxAltitude to become disabled for input when sphere is selected. When cylinder is selected, it should become enabled for input.

Every example I find is pretty simple but requires knowing exactly what the ID is, where in my code it is dynamically generated. This is an example of what I'm finding:

```
$(#maxAltitude).prop("disabled", true);
```

How can I do this when maxAltitude will be something more like: maxAltitude_10? There may be 1-n rows in a table, and I need to specifically disable the max altitude in the row where the dropdown select was changed.

I've tried jQuery and javascript but can't seem to find a good way to do this:

```
<option onclick="shapeSelect()" value="sphere">Sphere</option>
<option onclick="shapeSelect()" value="cylinder">Cylinder</option>

function shapeSelect() {
    var shapeSelects = document.getElementsByName("shapeSelect");
    var maxAlts = document.getElementsByName("maxAlt");
    for(var i = 0; i < shapeSelects.length; i++) {
        switch(shapeSelects[i].value) {
        case "sphere":
            maxAlts[I].disabled = True;
            break;
        case "cylinder":
            maxAlts[i].disabled = False;
        }
    }
}
```

With the above code I get: **SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier** whenever shapeSelect() is fired.

I've modified the code as follows:

```
<table class="myTable" id="myTable"></table>

$(table).find('tbody').append("<tr>name=\"tableRow\"</tr>"
        + "<td>"
          + "<select id=\"shapeSelect_" + rowCount + "></td>"
            + "<option value=\"sphere\">Sphere</option>"
            + "<option value=\"cylinder\">Cylinder</option>"
          + "</select>"
        + "</td>"
        + "<td><input type=\"text\" id=\"altitude_" + rowCount + "\"</td>"
        + "<td><input class=\"maxAltitudeInput\" type=\"text\" id=\"maxAltitude_" + rowCount + "\" disabled></td>"
        + "</tr>"

$('#myTable').on('change','.shapeSelector',function(){
    var shouldDisableInput = $(this).val() === 'sphere';
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.maxAltitudeInput').attr('disabled',shouldDisableInput);
}
```

And still nothing happens when I change the shape selector dropdown.

EDIT:

Apologies on the naming mismatches. My dev machine is on an airgapped network and I was hand jamming the post here on Stack Overflow. The rowCount variable was being created and incremented in another function. I was trying to only put relevant code in the post for brevity.

I *was* missing a class from shapeSelector. That was the missing link. It works now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery actually makes this really easy by binding `this` to whichever element triggered an event.

For instance, instead of writing a generic function for when that value changes, you could use jQuery to bind an event listener to them:

```
$('#myTable').on('change','.shapeSelector',function(){
    var shouldDisableInput = $(this).val() === 'sphere';
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.maxAltitudeInput').attr('disabled',shouldDisableInput);
}
```

You'll notice a few things in this snippet:

1. The element we are binding the listener to is the table, not the individual row. That's because the row is dynamic, and we don't want to have to keep adding listeners every time we add a row. Instead we add it to the parent which is stable, but then we specify that we are interested in its children that match ".shapeSelector"
2. The listener relies on class names, not IDs, since we want to match multiple copies of them, not just a specific one. So you'd need to add those class names or a similar way of matching more than one item
3. Inside the callback function that runs, you'll notice a couple uses of `this`. jQuery has bound that to the element that triggered the event listener, in this case, the `<select>` control. So when we use `this`, we have to think of it from that perspective. We can get its value by `$(this).val()`, we can find its parentt with `$(this).parent()`, etc. In this case, I'm travelling up to the nearest `tr`, then from there down to that `tr`'s input that I want to disable. You'd need to adjust a little depending on your dom.
4. Also note that `this` is a DOM element, not a jQuery result. That's why when we want to run more jQuery commands on it, we have to put it in $() again.

That's how I'd approach it. We don't have your entire code here, so you'll have to adjust a bit, but hopefully that pushes you off in the right direction.

**EDIT**

To be honest, there were a lot of naming mismatches and things that didn't line up. For instance, you were attempting to append onto a `tbody` tag, but that tag didn't exist. You were using a rowCount variable, but didn' ever set that up or increment it. The select tag sill didn't have the class name you were trying to use.

I suggest you look at your code piece by piece, ask yourself what you're telling the browser to do, and then do that instruction in your mind to make sure the computer can do it.

HTML:

```
<table class="myTable" id="myTable"><tbody></tbody></table>
```

JavaScript:

```
var rowCount = 0;

function addRow(){
   $('.myTable tbody').append(`<tr name="tableRow">
        <td> 
          <select class="shapeSelector" id="shapeSelect_${rowCount}">
            <option value="sphere">Sphere</option>
            <option value="cylinder">Cylinder</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td><input type="text" id="altitude_${rowCount}" /></td>
        <td><input class="maxAltitudeInput" type="text" id="maxAltitude_${rowCount}" disabled></td>"
        </tr>`);
   rowCount++;
}


$('.myTable').on('change','.shapeSelector',function(){
    var shouldDisableInput = $(this).val() === 'sphere';
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.maxAltitudeInput').attr('disabled',shouldDisableInput);
});

addRow();
addRow();
addRow();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/32vnjq81/

Comment: So does the hashtag in JQuery bind to name, id, or tag in the HTML? Something like #maxAltitude would need to be specifically one or the other depending on what I am using for my index (maxAltitude ID or name would be maxAltitude_5).

Comment: That's what I was saying, you need to give it something that applies to more than one. I'd add a class. (By the way, it's called a 'selector').

Comment: I edited the post with new code (sorry for the formatting, I couldn't quite get it right).

Comment: You have to add the class to the elements you create. When you append the select element, also add class="shapeSelector". And your input classes have to line up (you have the class maxAlititude on the element, but in the jQuery you are still using what I wrote, which is maxAltitudeInput.

Comment: I noticed the names not lining up and made the fix to the code in the post. The JQuery still doesn't seem to be doing anything when I run the code.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a complete working solution.

Comment: So it was the shapeSelector class declaration I was missing. I now understand what the JQuery selector seems to bind to in a statement. Thank you!